# adMob auto-closes on entering foreground

Tags: ios, swift, admob, interstitial

I implemented a test adMob with Firebase:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    interstitial.delegate = self
....}


func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "testVideo")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}

func interstitialWillDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    print("interstitialWillDismissScreen")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "adWasShowing")
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    if ... {
        ...
    } 
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
}
```

The problem is when I get an ad (5sec video) and take the app to background and then to foreground again

> interstitialWillDismissScreen and interstitialDidDismissScreen

automatically gets called resulting in closing the ad. I think many users will use this exploit to not stay on the video. Any idea on how to solve this?

I tried to set up a bool in UserDefaults in the "interstitialWillPresentScreen" and check it at "applicationWillEnterForeground", but I don't like this idea and also the interstitial request is not yet loaded (interstitialRequest must be recreated for every ad).